# Reimplement an algorithm to create a refine list

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, substring

I'm trying to reimplement an algorithm to create a refine keywords list. I don't have the original source code, only the tool .exe file, so I only have the input and the expected output.

The problem here is that the output of my function doesn't match with the output of the original one. Here's the code that I'm using:

```
string[] inputLines = File.ReadAllLines("Input.txt");
Dictionary<string, int> keywordsCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();
List<string> refineList = new List<string>();

//Get Keywords Count
foreach (string fileName in inputLines)
{
    string[] fileNameSplitted = fileName.Split('_');
    for (int i = 0; i < fileNameSplitted.Length; i++)
    {
        string currentKeyWord = fileNameSplitted[i];
        if (!string.Equals(currentKeyWord, "SFX", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            if (keywordsCount.ContainsKey(fileNameSplitted[i]))
            {
                keywordsCount[fileNameSplitted[i]] += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                keywordsCount.Add(fileNameSplitted[i], 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

//Get final keywords
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> keyword in keywordsCount)
{
    if (keyword.Value > 2 && keyword.Key.Length > 2)
    {
        refineList.Add(keyword.Key);
    }
}
```

The input file:

```
SFX_AMB_BIRDSONG
SFX_AMB_BIRDSONG_MISC
SFX_AMB_BIRDSONG_SEAGULL
SFX_AMB_BIRDSONG_SEAGULL_BUSY
SFX_AMB_BIRDSONG_VULTURE
SFX_AMB_CAVES_DRIP
SFX_AMB_CAVES_DRIP_AUTO
SFX_AMB_CAVES_LOOP
SFX_AMB_DESERT_CICADAS
SFX_AMB_EARTHQUAKE
SFX_AMB_EARTHQUAKE_SHORT
SFX_AMB_EARTHQUAKE_STREAMED
SFX_AMB_FIRE_BURNING
SFX_AMB_FIRE_CAMP_FIRE
SFX_AMB_FIRE_JET
SFX_AMB_FIRE_LAVA
SFX_AMB_FIRE_LAVA_DEEP
SFX_AMB_FIRE_LAVA_JET1
SFX_AMB_FIRE_LAVA_JET2
SFX_AMB_FIRE_LAVA_JET3
SFX_AMB_FIRE_LAVA_JET_STOP
SFX_AMB_UNDW_BUBBLE_RELEASE
SFX_AMB_UNDW_BUBBLE_RELEASE_AUTO
SFX_AMB_WATER_BEACH1
SFX_AMB_WATER_BEACH2
SFX_AMB_WATER_BEACH3
SFX_AMB_WATER_CANALS
SFX_AMB_WATER_FALL_HUGE
SFX_AMB_WATER_FALL_NORMAL
SFX_AMB_WATER_FALL_NORMAL2
SFX_AMB_WATER_FALL_NORMAL3
SFX_AMB_WATER_FOUNTAIN
SFX_CS_LUX_PORTAL_LIGHTNING
SFX_CS_LUX_PORTAL_LIGHTNING1
SFX_CS_LUX_PORTAL_LIGHTNING2
SFX_CS_LUX_PRIEST_COWER
SFX_CS_LUX_PRIEST_MEDAL
SFX_CS_LUX_PRIEST_MEDITATE
SFX_CS_LUX_PRIEST_SCREAM
SFX_CS_LUX_PRIEST_SNIFF1
SFX_CS_LUX_PRIEST_SNIFF2
SFX_CS_LUX_PRIEST_SPIRITS
SFX_CS_LUX_PRIEST_SPIRITS2
SFX_CS_LUX_PRIEST_SPIRITS3
SFX_CS_LUX_PRIEST_SURPRISE
SFX_MON_BM05_TOO_WALK1
SFX_MON_BM05_TOO_WALK2
SFX_MON_BM06_SQU_WALK1
SFX_MON_BM06_SQU_WALK2
SFX_MON_BR06_HAL_ATTACK1
SFX_MON_BR06_HAL_ATTACK2
SFX_MON_BR06_HAL_DIE
SFX_MON_BR06_HAL_HIT
SFX_MON_BR06_HAL_IDLE
SFX_MON_BR06_HAL_IDLE_EATING
SFX_MON_BR06_HAL_LAND1
SFX_MON_BR06_HAL_LAND2
SFX_MON_BR06_HAL_SCRAPE
SFX_MON_BR06_HAL_SLAM
SFX_MON_BR06_HAL_SURPRISE
SFX_MON_BR06_HAL_WALK1
SFX_MON_BR06_HAL_WALK2
SFX_MON_BU01_MUM_ATTACK1
SFX_MON_BU01_MUM_ATTACK2
SFX_MON_BU01_MUM_DIE
SFX_MON_BU01_MUM_HIT
SFX_MON_BU01_MUM_IDLE_RETRIEVE
SFX_MON_BU01_MUM_IDLE_RETRIEVE_GROW
SFX_MON_BU01_MUM_SURPRISE
SFX_MON_BU01_MUM_WALK1
SFX_MON_BU01_MUM_WALK2
SFX_WATER_SPLASH_BIG
SFX_WATER_SPLASH_BIG1
SFX_WATER_SPLASH_BIG2
SFX_WATER_SPLASH_BIG3
SFX_WATER_SPLASH_MED1
SFX_WATER_SPLASH_MED2
SFX_WATER_SPLASH_MED3
SFX_WATER_SPLASH_MEDIUM
SFX_WATER_SPLASH_OUT
SFX_WATER_SPLASH_OUT1
SFX_WATER_SPLASH_OUT2
SFX_WATER_SPLASH_SMALL
```

And the expected output (from the original tool):

```
AMB
MON
WATER
LUX
BR06
HAL
SPLASH
PRIEST
FIRE
BU01
MUM
LAVA
BIRDSONG
WALK1
WALK2
JET
IDLE
EARTHQUAKE
FALL
SURPRISE
BIG
CAVES
```

What should I modify to make that my method matches with the original output?

Thanks in advance!

-------EDIT
I've done some new discoveries:

->It is a method of approximately 100-130 lines.

->Use the Visual Basic methods InStr, Len, Right and Left

->Discards the word "SFX", and all words less than 3 characters long.

->It uses a combobox as a temporary list where it puts all the words that
appear more than once, and from here it takes out some words, which are the ones that are shown in the combobox visible to the user.

->For the first test case, that I've published, this is the discarded words list:

```
UNDW
BM05
BM06
SEAGULL
DRIP
BUBBLE
PORTAL
TOO
SQU
OUT
AUTO
RELEASE
NORMAL
LIGHTNING
SPIRITS
ATTACK1
ATTACK2
DIE
HIT
RETRIEVE
```

Comment: time to break out your debugger

Comment: Well, my method doesn't crash, it's just that in my output list there are words that should be in and words that shouldn't be. I don't end to understand the algorithm that the original tool uses.

Comment: debuggers are finding out why running programs dont do what you expect.

Comment: i mean if you dont know the algorithm then how can you write the program?

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. I've been trying to do some tests in the original tool, changing the input with the hope to find a pattern to write my method, but I have not been able.

Comment: What are the rules that you have, what is the specification of the algorithm? An expected output with some sample strings is just guessing.

Comment: Is the order important?

Comment: Why it contains Big but not Big1, Big2, Big3 while it contains Walk1 and Walk2? It seems to have arbitrary rules.

Comment: Hello! Yes, I think that the order is also important, another thing that I've just discovered is that skips the "words" where the length is less than 3. That's why skip CS

Comment: I've also thought the same about arbitrary rules, but the output is always the same. Seems to have a pattern specified, but difficult to understand.

Comment: @jms2505: Why is it important? This algorithm doesn't make sense at all. There are so many odd things that it clearly arbitrary or contains logic that is not obvious. For example why are the `LIGHTNING` tokens not part of the result. This is just one of many examples. The order also doesn't follow any rules.

Comment: Well this project where I'm working on, is a reimplementing of a tool done in VB6, the idea would be to make it as faithful to the original as possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241704/discussion-between-tim-schmelter-and-jms2505).

Comment: It’s hidden for a reason! Might be some experimental behaviour… still… machine learning with data feeds will be your friend I think.

Comment: So... Something separates the words [CAVES, SURPRISE, EARTHQUAKE] from PORTAL. PORTAL is the only word in the newly added list that doesn't have "serial numbers" attached to it that is repeated three times in the input. The three former words have the exact same pattern, but they are included in the output. Why? (Yes, this may be a too narrow way to look at the problem, I know.)

Comment: @Astrid E. I've added six more test cases, hope that can help

Comment: What;s the deal with the new test cases being so different? (case, language..)

Comment: I thought that probably would help to find the pattern that this algorithm uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could finally get it!!

I could finally figure it out, I had to use OllyDbg,Numega SmartCheck, and VB Decompiler tools, a lot of patience and voilà.

Here is the code, I've done it in VB.Net due to similarity with VB6:

```
'Clear comboboxes
Combo2.Items.Clear()
Combo3.Items.Clear()

'Start refining
Dim listboxItemsCount As Integer = listbox_SfxItems.Items.Count - 1
'Split only six words
For numberOfIterations As Integer = 0 To 5
    'Iterate listbox items
    For sfxItemIndex As Integer = 0 To listboxItemsCount
        'Iterate listbox items to find matches
        For sfxItemIndexSub As Integer = 0 To listboxItemsCount
            'Skip the line that we are checking in the previus loop
            If sfxItemIndex = sfxItemIndexSub Then
                Continue For
            End If
            'Get item from listbox
            Dim currentSfx As String = listbox_SfxItems.Items(sfxItemIndex)
            Dim wordToCheck As String = currentSfx
            'Split words
            If numberOfIterations > 0 Then
                For wordIndex = 1 To numberOfIterations
                    If InStr(1, wordToCheck, "_", CompareMethod.Binary) Then
                        Dim wordLength As Integer = Len(wordToCheck) - InStr(1, wordToCheck, "_", CompareMethod.Binary)
                        wordToCheck = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(wordToCheck, wordLength)
                    End If
                Next
            End If
            If InStr(1, wordToCheck, "_", CompareMethod.Binary) Then
                Dim wordLength As Integer = InStr(1, wordToCheck, "_", CompareMethod.Binary) - 1
                wordToCheck = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(wordToCheck, wordLength)
            End If
            'Find matches
            If StrComp("SFX", wordToCheck) <> 0 Then
                If Len(wordToCheck) > 2 Then
                    currentSfx = listbox_SfxItems.Items(sfxItemIndexSub)
                    If InStr(1, currentSfx, wordToCheck, CompareMethod.Binary) Then
                        'Get combo items count
                        Dim addNewItem As Boolean = True
                        For comboboxIndex As Integer = 0 To Combo2.Items.Count - 1
                            Dim comboWordItem As String = CType(Combo2.Items(comboboxIndex), ComboItemData).Name
                            'Check for duplicated
                            If InStr(1, comboWordItem, wordToCheck, CompareMethod.Binary) = 0 Then
                                Continue For
                            End If
                            'Update combo item with the word appearances count
                            currentSfx = CType(Combo2.Items(comboboxIndex), ComboItemData).Name
                            If StrComp(currentSfx, wordToCheck) = 0 Then
                                'Get current item data
                                Dim currentItemData As Integer = CType(Combo2.Items(comboboxIndex), ComboItemData).ItemData
                                'Update value
                                currentItemData += 1
                                CType(Combo2.Items(comboboxIndex), ComboItemData).ItemData = currentItemData
                            End If
                            'Don't add items in the combobox and quit loop
                            addNewItem = False
                            Exit For
                        Next
                        'Check if we have to add the new item
                        If addNewItem Then
                            Combo2.Items.Add(New ComboItemData(wordToCheck, 0))
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
Next

'Check final words
Combo3.Items.Add("All")
Combo3.Items.Add("HighLighted")

Dim quitLoop As Boolean = False
Do
    If Combo2.Items.Count > 0 Then
        Dim itemToRemove As Integer = -1
        'Get max value from the remaining words
        Dim maxWordAppearances As Integer = 0
        For itemIndex As Integer = 0 To Combo2.Items.Count - 1
            Dim itemData As Integer = CType(Combo2.Items(itemIndex), ComboItemData).ItemData
            maxWordAppearances = Math.Max(maxWordAppearances, itemData)
        Next
        'Get the item with the max value
        For index As Integer = 0 To Combo2.Items.Count - 1
            Dim itemData As Integer = CType(Combo2.Items(index), ComboItemData).ItemData
            If itemData = maxWordAppearances And itemToRemove = -1 Then
                itemToRemove = index
            End If
        Next
        'Remove and add items
        Dim itemStringName As String = CType(Combo2.Items(itemToRemove), ComboItemData).Name
        Combo3.Items.Add(itemStringName)
        Combo2.Items.RemoveAt(itemToRemove)
        'Check if we have to skip this loop
        If maxWordAppearances <= 5 Then
            quitLoop = True
        End If
    End If
Loop While quitLoop <> True
'Select the first item
Combo3.SelectedIndex = 0
```

Not sure if it could be optimized, but works as the original one, and outputs the same words with the same order.

If you want to test it, requires the following controls:
two comboboxes, Combo2 is the temporal one, and Combo3 the one that the user views. It also requires a listbox with the items to check.

The comboItemData class has been extracted from this site: https://www.elguille.info/colabora/puntonet/alvaritus_itemdataennet.htm

I've renamed Cls_lista to ComboItemData

Answer (score 0):

How about taking it as a block of text, splitting on line endings or underscores and getting the unique remnants:

```
File.ReadAllText(path)
  .Split(new[]{'\r','\n','_'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .Distinct();
```

Hang on.. maybe it's only words three plus length, that appear thrice or more:

```
File.ReadAllText(path)
  .Split(new[]{'\r','\n','_'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .GroupBy(w => w)
  .Where(g => g.Key.Length > 2 && g.Count() > 2)
  .Select(g => g.Key)
```

If you have a fixed list of words to exclude you can do e.g. `.Except(new[]{ "SFX", "..." })` on the end..

Comment: Thanks for your response, but unfortunately doesn't match entirely with the original output.

Comment: Hello! Just now I've discovered that seems to skip the words where the length is less than 3. And yes I think that probably the order is also important, If you want I can add more test cases in my question.

Comment: *the order is also important* - if that's the case I think you might need to post up on puzzling.se first, see if they can crack it then come here to get help implementing it. Is the original program that does the output a C# one?

Comment: But if we get the same output but in a different order, doesn't matter, would be also fine. No, the original tool was written in VB6.

Comment: I've added six more test cases, hope that can help

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with plain LINQ, use a `GroupBy` and convert it to a dictionary. On that Dictionary you can add additional criteria where you e.g. check the minimum amount of occurrences. You don't need to worry about several if-else conditions and keeps it pretty readable:

```cs
string[] inputLines = File.ReadAllLines("Input.txt");

var output = inputLines
    .SelectMany(s =>
        s.Split('_')
            .Where(w => w != "SFX")
        )
    .GroupBy(g => g)
    .ToDictionary(s => s.Key, s => s.Count())
    .Where(w => w.Key.Length > 2 && w.Value > 2);
```

[image]

Comment: It's as wrong as mine is; incorrectly has PORTAL and lacks JET/BIG

Comment: @CaiusJard I see!! Hmm…

Comment: Then I thought "let's strip numbers off the end of words on the end of a line.." but that brings more unwanted, like OUT..

Comment: It seems like when there is an item like Jet or Big without a number behind it (version 0) and there are items with a newer version, there should be at least 4 in total… this excludes Out. Maybe I’ll try something a bit later!

Comment: Even with that strategy the ordering will be too hard to determine. At first it's the # of occurrences, but at EARTHQUAKE it goes off.... Too little information is provided. Sorry!

Comment: Seems like an impossible job to me at this moment. Decomplication without some specific VB6 files isn't possible from what I've read. Even if this input list would work out, a slight variation might give another outcome... Maybe some Machine Learning solution might bring the answer? Feed it all possible inputs and predict the outcome?

Comment: yeah, sounds good. I could do this, but I don't know too much about machine learning. Could you tell me how it works and how to implement it?

Comment: Well, the basics are that you need to train the machine learning model. You have input and outputs that you can feed. As long as you feed enough data it will be predictable. Sometimes too hard for us to imagine, just rely on that fact :-) Checkout https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/ml-dotnet/get-started-tutorial/scenario

Comment: Hello! I've done some more discovers, I've updated the question.

Comment: I've added six more test cases, hope that can help

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a go. Can't figure out the ordering, and the performance is not top notch, but you get your required output selection for your one given example.

"SFX" *could* be excluded due to being (a) contained in *all* input items, or (b) the very first part of each input item, but I have kept it as a hard-coded string to exclude, in addition to "PORTAL". I really have no idea why "PORTAL" is excluded in the output.

Here, `Input` is a `string[]` with the example input provided in the question post.

```csharp
var excludedWords = new[] { "SFX", "PORTAL" };

var feasibleWords = Input
    .SelectMany(str => str.Split('_'))
    .Where(word =>
        word.Length > 2 &&
        !excludedWords.Contains(word));

var repeatedWords = feasibleWords
    .GroupBy(word => word)
    .Where(gr => gr.Count() > 2)
    .ToDictionary(
        gr => gr.Key,
        gr => gr.Count());

var serialWords = feasibleWords
    .Except(repeatedWords.Keys)
    .GroupBy(word => Regex.Replace(word, @"[\d]", string.Empty))
    .Where(gr => 
        gr.Contains(gr.Key) && 
        gr.Count() > 3)
    .ToDictionary(
        gr => gr.Key,
        gr => gr.Count());

var output = repeatedWords.Concat(serialWords)
    .OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Value) // Doesn't add much value, but oh well
    .Select(kvp => kvp.Key);

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, output));
```

Prints:

> AMB
> MON
> WATER
> LUX
> BR06
> HAL
> SPLASH
> FIRE
> PRIEST
> BU01
> MUM
> LAVA
> BIRDSONG
> FALL
> WALK1
> WALK2
> IDLE
> JET
> BIG
> CAVES
> EARTHQUAKE
> SURPRISE

Comment: Thank you, yes, you are right, in the original tool happens the same, it even shows a progress bar, and literally needs a minute for creating this list.

Comment: @jms2505 That's not enough help to increase my understanding, unfortunately. But it's interesting that Right has been used! Wonder what that's for?

Comment: I think it’s for the part where you use the regex /d for, to strip the number from the right.

Comment: @321X Ah, yeah, that could be it.

Comment: I've added six more test cases, hope that can help

Comment: @jms2505 I am giving up on this; wishing you the best of luck trying to figure it out. :)